# Using annotate on list

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Currently, I have a view that shows all my investments maturing within the next 5 years, for each client.  What I would like to do is show the total for each financial institution,  displayed like:

Institution | Amount | Maturity Amount

TD     | 1000 | 1250
Scotia | 1203 | 9383

etc

This is my code for showing the next 5 years worth of maturity investments.

```
#get the invesments maturing this year
        for p in plans:
            cur_inv = Investment.objects.all().filter(plan = p).order_by('financial_institution').filter(maturity_date__year = current_year)
            nxt_inv = Investment.objects.all().filter(plan = p).order_by('financial_institution').filter(maturity_date__year = next_yr)
            thr_inv = Investment.objects.all().filter(plan = p).order_by('financial_institution').filter(maturity_date__year = thr_yr)
            fr_inv = Investment.objects.all().filter(plan = p).order_by('financial_institution').filter(maturity_date__year = fr_yr)
            fv_inv = Investment.objects.all().filter(plan = p).order_by('financial_institution').filter(maturity_date__year = fv_yr)

            for inv in cur_inv:
                total += inv.amount or 0
            for inv in cur_inv:
                total_m += inv.maturity_amount or 0

            for inv in nxt_inv:
                total2 += inv.amount or 0
            for inv in nxt_inv:
                total_m2 += inv.maturity_amount or 0

            for inv in thr_inv:
                total3 += inv.amount or 0
            for inv in thr_inv:
                total_m3 += inv.maturity_amount or 0

            for inv in fr_inv:
                total4 += inv.amount or 0
            for inv in fr_inv:
                total_m4 += inv.maturity_amount or 0

            plan_list.append({
                'plan':p,
                'investment': cur_inv,
                'nxt_inv': nxt_inv,
                'thr_inv': thr_inv,
                'fr_inv': fr_inv,
                'fv_inv': fv_inv,
            })
```

I'm using a list to store all my plans so I can run a for loop for each plan on my template.

I have a similar view which does what I want this one to do but for only one plan, and I am not sure how to get it to work with multiple plans.

Here is my code for if it's just one selected plan.

```
#Calculate the holding totals with each company
        total_list = plan.investment_set.filter(maturity_date__gte= '%s-1-1' % current_year).values('financial_institution__abbr').annotate(Sum('maturity_amount')).order_by('financial_institution__abbr')
        context['list'] = total_list
```

If anyone could help that would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you might be able to get your database calculate this for you.

In SQL this might look something like:

```
SELECT sum(investment.amount)
FROM investment, maturity_date
WHERE investment.id = maturity_date.investment_id and year=%s
GROUP BY investment.amount
```

Have a look at [Django's documentation for aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/) and see if there's a fit for your problem.

On a side note, Django's queryset api is [generative](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#methods-that-return-new-querysets), so you can simplify the building of your query:

```
investments = Investment.objects.all().filter(plan = p).order_by('financial_institution')
cur_inv = investments.filter(maturity_date__year = current_year)
nxt_inv = investments.filter(maturity_date__year = next_yr)
thr_inv = investments.filter(maturity_date__year = thr_yr)
fr_inv = investments.filter(maturity_date__year = fr_yr)
fv_inv = investments.filter(maturity_date__year = fv_yr)
```

EDIT: I haven't tried this myself, but [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by) of the aggregation documentation looks like a good start.